# The range of velocity in Maxwell Velocity Distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, density-of-states

If we see the formula for velocity distributions in x,y, and z-direction their range of velocity goes from -infinity to +infinity but when we take the whole velocity distribution, the range goes from 0 to infinity in 3d. Why?

And what does this imply when we see velocity distribution in x-direction their velocity can never be zero is what I cannot realize.

Comment: Because you transform from $v$ to $1/2 m v^2$...

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape can you explain it more clearly.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution under "distribution for the speed"

Comment: You are describing the Maxwell speed distribution, not the velocity distribution.  The former has no sign, so it goes from zero to infinity while the later does have a sign and goes from negative to positive infinity.

Comment: @honeste_vivere when you sign, what does that means

Comment: Speeds are positive definite quantities (except when zero) so they don't have a sign (i.e., positive or negative) attached to them.  Velocities are speeds with an associated direction, so have a sign attached to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maxwell distribution
$$f(v)dv\propto v^2 e^{-\beta mv^2/2}dv$$
gives the distribution of the magnitude of the velocity vector or the length of the velocity vector. The length of the vector can not be negative, it can run from $0$ to $\infty$.

---

If you look for the distribution of $x$ component of velocity, then It look like
$$g(v_x)dv_x\propto e^{-\beta mv_x^2/2}$$
The range of this distribution is $[-\infty,\infty]$ as it should be.

Comment: Your first equation is the Maxwell speed distribution, not the velocity distribution.